# Importing Google Docs documents into Google Code project

Tags: google-drive, google-code

I am hosting projects in Google Code. I have some documents (Specs, Requirements, etc.) in Google Documents as documents and spreadsheets. I need to link these documents as *Downloads* or *Wikis* in Google Code.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

you make the documents public and then either:

- share the link to these public documents
- make a public webpage of these documents (and link to them)
- make a public webpage of these documents and embed them into the wiki via iframes (if possible)

follow the guidelines from http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=180199&hl=en

if you want to give access of the .pdf or .doc or .xls versions of the documents, you have to export them manually to your desktop and then upload them to google-code wiki as "downloadable files".